# Queries enviando dados para outra Tabela

Tags: c#, sql

Ola, estou precisando de uma ajuda preciso pegar dados usando where para passar para outra tabela :
http://image.prntscr.com/image/712077abe80f4033a016675279a7a0dd.png (tabela de contas )

No print, mostra o " UserID(int) " eu preciso pegar todos os " UserID(int) " usando where

http://image.prntscr.com/image/fc86456e11994997b1d25b8b3480375c.png
nesse print mostra a tabela para onde o UserID vai

Na questão do where (Where LoginCount=3) 2 = offline 3=online

O objetivo disso é enviar items (do jogo) para quem esta online)

Comment: Guilherme o que você já tentou? Dê uma lida em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.WarsEvento (NickName,Status,UserID) SELECT NckName,Status,UserID FROM dbo.Sys_Users_Detail WHERE LoginCount=3
```

Comment: Então eu posso usar 2 query em uma string ?

Comment: Sim, são chamados de sub queries.
teste e veja se é o que precisa